# Child Div overflow x - y and scroll on parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">

      <ul>
         <li>one</li>
         <li>A very long name. A very long name. A very long name. A very long name. A very long name. A very long name. </li>
         <li>Three</li>
      </ul>

   </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {width:170px; border:1px solid #000; padding:20px}
#child {border:1px solid #F00}
```

I have not applied width property to child div. What I want is to see horizontal and vertical scrollbars on parent div.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NanzR/

Expected output: 
[image]

Comment: What width do you want to give the child?

Comment: I do not want to specify any width to child div. It should occupy width of longest name. That is, a li value show not appear on the next line.

Comment: I don't understand. You want it to be wide as the longest word in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/NanzR/3/)

```
#parent {
    width:170px;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 170px;
}
#child {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```